# C# Console -- String Splitting/Joining

Tags: c#

I have a basic console app written but it is giving me errors in a few places which I have marked. This is my first time trying to split strings and such and I cannot figure out how to use the constructor to spit out a random array of 'hands.'

```
namespace PokerGame
{
public class Display
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Poker Game!");
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + "Enter 'deal' to start game!");


        Console.WriteLine("Hand is: {0}");
    }
}

public class NewDeal
{
    public string card;

    public string[] suit = {"♥,♠,♦,♣"};
    public char delimiter = ',';
    public string[] rank = {"A,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K"};

    public string dealer(string suit, string rank)
    {
        string[] singleSuit = suit.Split(delimiter);
        string[] singleRank = rank.Split(delimiter);

        foreach(string s in singleSuit)
        {
            string card = s + singleRank;
        }

        return card;
    }

    public NewDeal()
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: There's multiple things wrong with your code. for instance, `dealer` parameters will hide the class variables. You're also trying to use `delimiter` as an array while it's a single char. You'll also have to decide if you want your method to really be `static` or not, because your variables are not static. You're also returning `card` in your `foreach` loop, preventing it from running.... There's a lot of issues here, so it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

namespace PokerGame
{
    public class Display
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Poker Game!");

```
        Console.WriteLine("Pick a card?(\"no\" to exit): ");


        string sentinelValue = Console.ReadLine();

        NewDeal oNewDeal = new NewDeal();

        Random newCard = new Random(System.DateTime.Now.Second);

        string _newCard = "";


        while (sentinelValue != "no")
        {
            _newCard = oNewDeal.getCards(newCard.Next(0, oNewDeal.suit.Length - 1), newCard.Next(0, oNewDeal.rank.Length - 1));
            Console.Write("Card: {0}\n", _newCard);
            Console.WriteLine("Pick a card?(\"no\" to exit): ");
            sentinelValue = Console.ReadLine();

        }
            Console.Read();

    }
}

public class NewDeal
{
    public string card = "";

    public string[] suit = new string[] { "♥","♠","♦","♣" };

    public const char DELIMETER = ',';

    public string[] rank = new string[] {"A","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};


    public string getCards(int _suit, int _rank)
    {
        return card = rank[_rank] + suit[_suit];
    }


}
```

}

Comment: well I understand it better now but my problem is I cannot return a "card" using this method it gives me an error. I have not tried yours yet. When I try to return 'card' it says it conflicts with the previous declaration...

Comment: and why did you not pass arguments to dealer()??

Comment: let me know the logic of your program, what do you expect it to do. does the user suppose to enter some value or something, because your asking it but you aren't retrieving nothing

Comment: Yes I haven't made the logic for the users input yet but basically the user enters something and the system prints out a 'hand' which is a set of 'cards.' Each card is a suit and rank. Thats all...

Comment: well, i modified the program to my way, the point is that the computer chooses 4 card randomly, i hope that's what you want

Comment: test it and let me know

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Im going to use this to work towards my solution! Its the right direction I just need to study this a bit!